# How to rename an external secret in Docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

Is there a way to remap an external secret to another name?

Say i have this secret in my docker-compose file:

```
DATABASE_URL_STAGING:
external: true
```

Can the DATABASE_URL_STAGING be renamed to DATABASE_URL inside the compose file?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no command to update the name of a secret. There isn't even a docker engine api endpoint for that. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/SecretUpdate specifically mentions "Currently, only the Labels field can be updated."

There *might* be ways to achieve your goal by bypassing the docker engine, but if there are, there would be a high chance that they break in a future update.

Otherwise, you can create a new secret, then make sure the old secret is not being used anymore, and use `docker secret rm <secret_name>` to remove it.

Alternatively, depending on what you really need, it might be enough for you to "alias" your secret within the scope of your compose file:

```yaml
secrets:
    DATABASE_URL:
        external: true
        name: DATABASE_URL_STAGING

services:
    my_service:
        ...
        secrets:
            - DATABASE_URL
```

Your external secret name would be `DATABASE_URL_STAGING`, but you could use `DATABASE_URL` in the compose file.